# passing ellipsis arguments to map function purrr package, R

Tags: r, ellipsis, purrr

I want to use ellipsis parameters inside map function of purrr package. this is a toy example:

```
f1<-function(x,a=NA,b=NA,prs=seq(0, 1, 0.25),SW=T){
  if(SW){
    res<-data.frame(name1=a,name2=b,t(quantile(x, prs, na.rm = T)),  mean=mean(x, na.rm = T), sd=sd(x, na.rm = T),
                    NAs=length(x[is.na(x)]),n=length(x[!is.na(x)]),SWp=shapiro.test(x)$p.value,stringsAsFactors =F)
  }else
  {
    res<-data.frame(name1=a,name2=b,t(quantile(x, prs, na.rm = T)),  mean=mean(x, na.rm = T), sd=sd(x, na.rm = T),
                    NAs=length(x[is.na(x)]),n=length(x[!is.na(x)]),stringsAsFactors =F)
  }
return(res)
}

f1(c(NA,rnorm(25),NA),SW=F)
f1(c(NA,rnorm(25),NA))
```

now I want to use f1 inside another function f2:

```
f2<-function(df,...){
  res<-map_df(colnames(df),~f1(df[,.],a=.,...))
  return(res)
}
```

where ... is intended mainly to manipulate SW and a or b parameters in f1 function. however f2 is not doing what I want as can be seen here

```
f2(iris[,-5])
f2(iris[,-5],SW=F)
```

I appreciate any guide in how to use addecuatelly ... inside map

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to pass the ellipses through the `map_df()` call as well. Otherwise they can't get into the inner `f1()` call.

```
f2 <- function(df, ...){
  res <- map_df(colnames(df), ~f1(df[,.], a=., ...), ...)
  return(res)
}
```

Comment: You might also need to pass ellipsis into the anonymous function itself, so that instead of `~`, you actualy spell out `function(.x, ...)` and replace `.` with `.x` everywhere if your functional sequence

Comment: I agree with @dmi3kno, I think one needs the `function(.x, ...)` construct!? See my post below, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also capture the ellipses early on in your second function, and use `do.call` to add them to your first function later on. This makes it more explicit where and how they are used.

```
f2 <- function(df, ...){
  params <- list(...)
  res <- map_df(colnames(df), ~ do.call(
    f1, c(list(x = df[,.], a=.), params)))
  return(res)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MrFlick solution did not work for me: I think indeed you also need to pass the `...` to the anonymous function, which then requires using `function(x,...)` instead of `~` (as suggested by @dmi3kno).

That means you need the quite surprising triple `...` call:

```
map(x, function(x, ...) mean(x, trim=0, ...), ...)
```

Example:

```r
library(purrr)
x <- list(c(1,2), c(1,2,NA))
fo1 <- function(...) map(x, ~mean(., trim=0, ...), ...)
fo2 <- function(...) map(x, function(x, ...) mean(x, trim=0, ...), ...)

fo1()
#> Warning in if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]: the condition has length > 1 and only
#> the first element will be used

#> Warning in if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]: the condition has length > 1 and only
#> the first element will be used
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1.5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1.5

fo2()
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1.5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] NA
fo2(na.rm=TRUE)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1.5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I've found that `rlang::exec()` allows you to pass ... to `purrr::map()` when combined with an anonymous function, like this:

```
f2 <- function(df, ...){
  res <- map(colnames(df), function(x) rlang::exec("f1", df[,x], ...))
  return(res)
}
```