# Why do I need to quote-unquote dots when passing them to a mapped function in purrr?

Tags: r, purrr, tidyeval

As I understand, normally you don't need to quote or unquote dots when they are not being modified (e.g. by changing their names). This example makes it seem like I don't really understand how that works, however.

Here we have a function that relies on dots to select columns for nesting. All it does is add a column from the `foo` argument, and then nest all columns not mentioned in the dots.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dots_fun <- function(df, foo, ...) {
  df %>%
    mutate(foo = foo) %>%
    nest(data = -c(...))
}

dots_fun(mtcars, "a", cyl)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl data              
#>   <dbl> <list>            
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 × 11]> 
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 × 11]>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 × 11]>
```

I want to be able to map this function, by calling it with different arguments. A naive approach to doing this by using a normal anonymous function syntax fails with a confusing error:

```r
list_of_foos <- c("a", "b")

mapping_fun1 <- function(df, foos, ...) {
  map(
    .x = foos,
    .f = ~ dots_fun(df = df, foo = .x, ...)
  )
}

mapping_fun1(mtcars, foos = list_of_foos, cyl)
#> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x The column `a` doesn't exist.
```

Nor does it help if I just move the dots outside of the anonymous function. It no longer errors, but fails to nest on `cyl` as desired.

```r
mapping_fun2 <- function(df, foos, ...) {
  map(
    .x = foos,
    .f = ~ dots_fun(df = df, foo = .x),
    ...
  )
}
mapping_fun2(mtcars, foos = list_of_foos, cyl)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   data              
#>   <list>            
#> 1 <tibble [32 × 12]>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   data              
#>   <list>            
#> 1 <tibble [32 × 12]>
```

I managed to get it to work by splicing the dots into the anonymous function, but I don't really understand why this was necessary. (You can also get it to work by reversing the order of the arguments of the mapped function and supplying all arguments through the `...` of `map`, but then `dots_fun` has the "wrong" argument order. It doesn't work if you use a `function()` style anonymous function to reverse the argument order)

```r
mapping_fun3 <- function(df, foos, ...) {
  dots <- enquos(...)
  map(
    .x = foos,
    .f = ~ dots_fun(df = df, foo = .x, !!!dots)
  )
}

mapping_fun3(mtcars, foos = list_of_foos, cyl)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl data              
#>   <dbl> <list>            
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 × 11]> 
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 × 11]>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 × 11]>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl data              
#>   <dbl> <list>            
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 × 11]> 
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 × 11]>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 × 11]>
```

My question is: **in what condition/situation do you need to quote and unquote `...` to pass them safely through functions?** and how does that condition apply here?

Comment: What version of `tidyr` are you using? I get errors when calling `dots_fun(mtcars, "a", cyl)` (`cyl` not found). I used `tidyr_1.0.2`

Comment: I think the problem is related to the fact you need to pass the ellipses though both the `map` and inner function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215325/passing-ellipsis-arguments-to-map-function-purrr-package-r but i'm having a hard time replicating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you need to pass the `...` though each level of function call. So the `...` both have to pass through `map()` as well as your inner function.

I could not get your example to work with `nest()`, so I made a version that uses `select()` instead

```
dots_fun <- function(df, foo, ...) {
  df %>%
    mutate(foo = foo) %>%
    select(...)
}
```

And then, it doesn't seem you can actually use the `as_mapper` syntax with `...` and non-standard evaluation via [this github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/710) so you need to explicitly create an anonymous function so the iterated value isn't passed a second time in the `...` values as well. [Hadley said](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/367#issuecomment-363089586) the `~` syntax is only for "simple" functions and not those with `...`. So a working mapping function might look like this

```
mapping_fun1 <- function(df, foos, ...) {
  map(
    .x = foos,
    .f = function(x, ...) dots_fun(df = df, foo = x, ...),
    ...
  )
}
mapping_fun1(mtcars, foos = list_of_foos, cyl, gear)
```

We pass the `...` though `map()`, through our anonymous function, and finally into `dots_fun`. If you break that chain at any point, it falls apart.

Comment: Nice answer. The technical reason that `...` doesn't work this way in lambda-formulas is that they use the dots for another purpose, so you can refer to arguments as `..1`, `..2` etc.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! It makes a lot more sense now